# Design pattern for child classes?

Tags: c#, parent-child

I have a class with some child (inner, not derived) classes.  Ideally, I'd like some fields of the child classes to be modifiable by the parent, but not be public.  Is there a design in C# that accomplishes this?  I can think of no way to use the typical access modifiers (protected, private, public, etc)

For example, imagine

```
Class Car{
    private Wheel wheel;
    Class Wheel
    {
        //I want this to be only accessible within Car and Wheel
        private int wheelSize;
    }
}
```

So, That's not my real code, but conveys the idea of what I want to do just fine.

Comment: The field of the nested class would have to be `internal` at least. But since the nested class `Wheel` in itself is private (or so it looks in your example), maybe that's not a real problem?

Comment: I think you're looking for the object Composition pattern.

Comment: It is called "nested" class.  You can declare the Wheel class private and make wheelSize public.

Comment: That makes sense too - I wasn't really clear with what my intention was with regards to the Wheel class, but if it too is completely restricted to only be used inside Car, that works, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could derive a private inner class from `Wheel` that has additional public members. The `Wheel` class would be abstract. this ensures that no instance of it can be created. Create a static method that creates wheels. The method would create a `PrivateWheel` but return it as `Wheel`. Wheels would always be exposed as `Wheel` but efectively be of type `PrivateWheel`.

```
public class Car {

    private PrivateWheel wheel;

    public Wheel { get { return wheel; } }

    public abstract class Wheel
    {
    }             

    private class PrivateWheel : Wheel
    {
        public int WheelSize { get; set; }
    }

    public static Wheel CreateWheel()
    {
        return new PrivateWheel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great idea. But you have to consider the possibility that code outside the `Car` class could derive from the nested `Car.Wheel` class.

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen: As long as code outside cannot inject its derived class into `Car`, that's not a problem.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes No, you're right, but it would still, in a sense, be a `Wheel` without a `WheelSize`.